# Как реализовать серверное ожидание ответа на вопрос

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, socket.io, promise

Необходимо реализовать викторину со свободным ответом (например: что где когда).

Алгоритм следующий:

1. сервер выбирает вопрос из базы… отправляет его через сокеты пользователям и запускает таймер.
2. пользователи отвечают на вопрос (в т.ч. неправильно)
3. варианты ответов пользователей улетают сокетами на сервер, где проверяются на соответствие правильному ответу на текущий вопрос (в теле socket.on())
4. в случае правильного ответа алгоритм повторяется.

Сложность возникает в момент когда вопрос отправлен и необходимо встать в "ожидание" правильного ответа. Думал реализовать через Promise. Но не могу понять как вызвать resolve из тела другого вызова, например через event, поскольку метод resolve должен быть определен в теле определения Promis'а.

Возможно есть более элегантные решения.

Comment: А зачем явно вставать в ожидание именно ответа ? У вас должен быть общий обработчик любых сообщений от пользователей. За каждым пользователем у вас наверняка закреплена некая управляющая структура. Когда вы пользователю отправили вопрос помечаете в ней что мы ждем ответ на вопрос такой то (ссылка на объект вопроса). И так же ждете тот самый таймер. Когда пришел ответ помечаете в структуре пользователя что ответ получен. По таймеру проходите по всем пользователям и смотрите приходили ли ответы

Comment: Пользователей много. Структура пользователей реализована библиотекой socket.io. Навесить на объект Io дополнительную структуру я конечно могу, но не будет ли это костылем? И

Comment: Я вот не понимаю что вам промис даст. Предположим вы можете вызвать resolve снаружи. Дальше что, придет событие, вы вызовете резолв и что он сделает ? Как вы потом на таймауте поймете кто отвечал а кто нет ?